# Dynamically retrieve relevant data from JSON and copy to SQL Table through Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, json, azure, factory

I am looking for an easy way to dynamically copy data from JSONs to SQL tables. The JSONs all have the same setup where the data is mentioned after fields like so:

```
  {
    "name": "Employees",
    "description": "Employeedata",
    "fields": [
      {
        "id": "EmployeeId",
        "fieldId": "U001",
        "dataType": "string",
        "label": "Employee",
        "length": 15,
        "controlType": 5,
        "decimals": 0,
        "decimalsFieldId": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "PersonId",
        "fieldId": "U003",
        "dataType": "string",
        "label": "EmpID",
        "length": 15,
        "controlType": 5,
        "decimals": 0,
        "decimalsFieldId": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "EmployerId",
        "fieldId": "U002",
        "dataType": "string",
        "label": "Employer",
        "length": 15,
        "controlType": 5,
        "decimals": 0,
        "decimalsFieldId": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The main structure is the same, so the relevant data is always after the fields property. However, the columns and corresponding data differs for each JSON.

When I perform the copy activity as is, the table ends up like this:

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Employees | Employeedata |

What I want is something like this:

| id | fieldId | datatype | label | length | controlType | decimals | decimalsFieldId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EmployeeId | U001 | string | Employee | 15 | 5 | 0 |  |
| PersonId | U003 | string | EmpID | 15 | 5 | 0 |  |
| EmployerId | U002 | string | Employer | 15 | 5 | 0 |  |

I am looking for a way to copy only the arrays after fields to an SQL table without having to manually assign a mapping for each JSON.

Comment: In SQL (all dialects, not just Oracle) the output of a query must have a fixed, known number of columns in the output. It is impossible to generate an unknown number of columns in the output if you are using a static SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Move JSON file to SQL DB by the copy activity, provide JSON as source.

[image]

Provide SInk as SQL database.

([image])

In the mapping field  need to import schema and enable **Advance editor** field, need to select options in **Collection reference** field.

([image])

Delete these column fields to get expected result as per the requirement.

([image])

Result get as we expected in SQL Database.

([image])